# AWK command to display columns as rows

Tags: unix, awk, foreach

```
./pkg_FC.mwlib

TILE_FC:1
TILE_FC:2
TILE_FC:3
TILE_FC:4
```

I am able to bring in this result using the awk command. But I need the output to be

`./pkg_FC.mwlib TILE_FC:1 TILE_FC:2 TILE_FC:3 TILE_FC:4`

How to bring about this output. Also how to write this output to a file. I am using the following script using foreach to get the above output.

```
foreach libname ( `find . -name "*mwlib"` )
echo $libname
ls -l $libname/FRAM | awk '{print $9}'
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Keep the strings in an awk array then [join them](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Join-Function.html)

Comment: I don't get it. Does this need anything more than printing each line, following each line with a space instead of a newline? Use redirection (`>` or `>>`) to write to a file.

Comment: where should I add the >> or > to output to a file? I tried but since it a foreach loop it is not writing all the results

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong tools and violating 2 fundamental rules of shell programming:

1. Never write `for file in $(command)`, and
2. Never parse the output of `ls`.

The UNIX command to find files is named `find`. Look for `-printf` and `-exec` in its man page, and also look up the man page for `xargs` and `stat`.

If you must loop on file names output from some command the syntax is this or similar:

```
command | while IFS= read -r file; do
    ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For the transposition, you could do:

```
$ printf "TILE_FC:%d\n" {1..4} | awk 'ORS=(NR%4?" ":RS)'
TILE_FC:1 TILE_FC:2 TILE_FC:3 TILE_FC:4

$ printf "TILE_FC:%d\n" {1..6} | awk 'ORS=(NR%4?" ":RS)'
TILE_FC:1 TILE_FC:2 TILE_FC:3 TILE_FC:4
TILE_FC:5 TILE_FC:6

$ printf "TILE_FC:%d\n" {1..8} | awk 'ORS=(NR%4?" ":RS)'
TILE_FC:1 TILE_FC:2 TILE_FC:3 TILE_FC:4
TILE_FC:5 TILE_FC:6 TILE_FC:7 TILE_FC:8
```

Change the `4` in `NR%4` if you want the width to be different.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but the pattern is not TILE_FC.. it varies like TILE_FC_GPIO TILE_FC_SERDES and so on.. so from ls command I get the list and from that list I want to create the above said pattern. 

./pkg_flipchip_lvds.mwlib

TILE_LVDS411_6L8L_180:1
TILE_LVDSPVT_6L8L_180:1

this is a sample output using ls command..

Comment: Is it file names or the contents of files?

Comment: file names.. ./pkg_flipchip_lvds.mwlib is the library name and rest are the files inside it

Comment: If they are file names INSIDE of a file -- awk / perl /python are your best bet with dealing with these; if they are file name produced in a pipe or as the result of a process -- Bash / sh / zsh are fine. Clarify please -- files names INSIDE a file OR file names produce by Bash or a pipe?

Comment: these are files name inside a folder.. say Folder A has 1 2 3 4 files. when i use the above ls and awk command I m getting the output as one column, but I need it as a row